# 'solvergraphics.pyde' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, call

I am trying to call a processing file from my code and it works for one file called Graphics.pyde but not another called solvergraphics.pyde. I am really confused at why. They are both formatted the same, and I have added them both to the VS code workspace (not sure if this helps). The main code from which I am calling the two files is in a folder containing 2 files one for each of the codes. Any help much appreciated. The code to call the other code is below

```
subprocess.call("solvergraphics.pyde", shell = True)
```

Comment: So prove it: copy that filename into your clipboard, the paste it into an empty file. Then copy the filename that's in your filesystem, and paste that into the same file on the next line. And now that you've not typed anything but just took the literal data that was in your code and filesystem: _are they identical_? And if they are, expand on what "it works" means. Because that doesn't tell anyone [what you expected to have happen, and what happened instead](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe in code you changed folder and now it search next file in different folder. Maybe first try `/full/path/to/file.pyde`. You could also check `Current Working Directory` before you run process. `print( os.getcwd() )` - to see if you still work in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves the path of the workspace. When you run the file, CMD is located in the current workspace. If you do not put the .pyde files under the workspace, it may not recognize it.

This can works for me:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please ensure that the folder where CMD is located contains the .pyde file.